# how to convert sting of different date format in to single date format in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i have some of my date as 26-07-10 and others as 4/8/2010 as string type in a csv. i want them to be in single format like 4/8/2010 so that i can parse them and group them each year. Is there a function in python or pandas help me?

Comment: As you have mixed format you'll have to parse them differently, are your dates only in these 2 formats? Also the second form is an invalid form as it doesn't have zero filled values

Comment: yes just two format. but something like general answer can be more helpful.

Comment: Hmm actually it seems `to_datetime` and `parse_dates` param of `read_csv` is man/woman enough to handle both forms

Comment: The displayed format is irrelevant if you convert the column to `datetime` `dtype` as you can group on the year attribute `dt.year`

Answer (score 0):

You can parse these date forms using `parse_dates` param of `read_csv` note however for ambiguous forms it may fail for instance if you gave month first forms mixed with day first:

```
In [7]:
t="""date
26-07-10
4/8/2010"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), parse_dates=[0])
df

Out[7]:
        date
0 2010-07-26
1 2010-04-08
```

You can alter the displayed format by changing the string format using `dt.strftime`:

```
In [10]:
df['date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

Out[10]:
0    26/07/2010
1    08/04/2010
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Really though it's better to keep the column as a `datetime` you can then groupby on year:

```
In [11]:
t="""date,val
26-07-10,23
4/8/2010,5567"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), parse_dates=[0])
df

Out[11]:
        date   val
0 2010-07-26    23
1 2010-04-08  5567

In [12]:    
df.groupby(df['date'].dt.year).mean()

Out[12]:
       val
date      
2010  2795
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `parse-date` parameter of `pd.read_csv()` as mentioned by @EdChum 
Alternatively, you could typecast them to a standard format, like that of `datetime.date` as follows:

```
import io
import datetime
t=u"""date
26-07-10
4/8/2010"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), parse_dates=[0])
df.date.astype(datetime.date)
df
```

out:

```
    date
0   2010-07-26  
1   2010-04-08
```